# object initialisation can determine member was defaulted or not?

Tags: c#

If I have a class

```
class widget {
    public int theNum;
    public string theName;
}
```

and I initalise like this

```
widget wgt = new widget { thename="tom" };
```

`theNum` will be zero.

Is there a way for me to examine the instance wgt to determine that the member theNum was defaulted i.e. excluded from the object initialisation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as `theNum` is a field you cannot tell if it was left uninitialized or if it was explicitly initialized to its default value (which in this case is `0`, but could be different if you had `public int theNum = 42`).

If `theNum` were a property then you could set a flag from within the property setter that allowed you to determine if the setter was invoked, no matter what value you set the property to. For example:

```
class widget {
    private int theNum;
    private bool theNumWasSet;
    public string theName;

    public int TheNum
    {
        get { return theNum; }
        set { theNumWasSet = true; theNum = value; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One option would be to change `theNum` to be an `int?` instead... then the default value would be the null value, which is different from 0.

I would expect those to be public *properties* rather than public fields, mind you - in which case you could make the *property* type `int`, keeping `int?` as the backing field type and providing some other way of checking for initialization, by testing whether the field value was null.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `int` use an `int?` (which is a short-hand for `System.Nullable<int>`. then, if nobody initializes it to a valid int, its going to be null.

Comment: And if somebody initializes it to `null`?

Comment: @Jon why would you care about that?

Comment: I don't know, but if you *don't* care about that then you can always check with `if (theNum == 0)` without going into nullable territory at all.